# Undefined method 'map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tendo este problema caso o validador encontre algum erro após enviar o formulário. Acho que pode ser por que minha variável de instância, @users, está nil?

Eu seto ela no controller com o before_action, então não deveria ter este problema, correto?

Controller:

```
class EnterprisesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :filter_user, only: [:new, :edit]

  def new
    @enterprise = Enterprise.new
    respond_with(@enterprise)
  end

  def edit
  end

  private
    def filter_user
      @users = User.where("role = 'customer' AND ID NOT IN ( SELECT user_id FROM ENTERPRISES WHERE USER_ID IS NOT NULL)")
    end
end
```

View:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@enterprise) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="inputs">
    <%= f.input :name, label: 'Nome' %>
    <%= f.input :corporate_name, label: 'Razão Social' %>
    <%= f.input :phone, label: 'Telefone' %>
    <%= f.input :cnpj, label: 'CNPJ' %>
    <%= f.input :state_registration, label: 'Inscrição Estadual' %>
    <%= f.input :adress, label: 'Endereço' %>
    <%= f.input :number, label: 'Número' %>
    <%= f.input :district, label: 'Bairro' %>
    <%= f.input :city, label: 'Cidade' %>
    <%= f.input :cep, label: 'CEP' %>
    <%= f.label :user_id, 'Usuário' %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:user_id, @users, :id, :email, {include_blank: true}) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Pesquisei na internet o que poderia ser, e encontrei uma solução; consultar o banco diretamente da view. Mas isto viola os princípios MVC, então teria de consultar no Controller mesmo, mas não consigo resolver o problema.

Comment: Onde está dando o erro? No collection_select?

Comment: Isso. Ele fala que a variável de instância é nil.

Comment: vc rodou essa query do filter_user no console? ela retorna dados?

Comment: Sim, normal. Somente quando o ActiveRecord retorna algum erro de preenchimento do formulário, que dá esse problema.

Comment: Uma boa prática é evitar o compartilhamento de variáveis de instância do controlador com a camada de visualização. Uma solução um pouco melhor é definir um método `users` no controller que retorna a coleção de usuários e passa-lo diretamente para o `f.collection_select`. Dessa forma você define uma interface pública para seu controller (e sinaliza uma dependência da view para com esse método. Nesse caso não haveria necessidade de um `before_filter`, já que o método vai ser executado quando for necessário apenas (quando for explicitamente chamado).

Comment: Por exemplo, eu definiria um método users_collection, e chamaria o método desse jeito? f.collection_select users_collection()